# ES6 get properties from nested objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, javascript-objects

i'm doing a project with VueJS, Lodash and Babel, and my problem is that i need to populate a sidebar in my app with routes from a *routes.js* file. Problem is i don't really know how i can retrieve the data i need.

```
export default [
  {
    path: "/admin/login",
    name: "admin.login",
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: "/admin",
    component: MasterLayout,
    meta: { auth: true },
    children: [
      {
        path: "/admin/dashboard",
        alias: "/",
        menu: { text: "", icon: ""},
        name: "admin.dashboard",
        component: DashboardIndex
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/403',
    name: 'error.forbidden',
    component: ErrorForbidden
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    name: 'error.notfound',
    component: ErrorPageNotFound
  }
];
```

That is my routes file, i basically need to iterate over each route, check if it has **children** or a **menu** property, if it has a menu it gets added to my list of *sidebar items*, and it's children get added as well  with their own **menu** properties being withdrawn

In the end i'd like to get something like the following

```
sidebarItems: [
 {
  name: 'Dashboard',
  icon: 'dashboard',
  name: 'admin.dashboard'
 }, 
 {
  name: 'OtherRoute',
  icon: 'other-route',
  name: 'admin.other-route',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'SubRoute',
      icon: 'sub-route',
      name: 'admin.sub'
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

This should only account for the routes that contain a **menu** property.

Comment: How the same objects can have 2 `name` properties? `name: 'Dashboard'` and name: 'admin.dashboard' for example

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee they are different objects, the first is the raw `routes.js` object the other one a different one generated from that initial object at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You basically need iterate recursive over the array, so please try this:

```
function iterateArrayRoutes(routeArray) {
  if(routeArray instanceof Array) {
    var routeFormatted = routeArray.reduce(function(last, route){
      if (route.hasOwnProperty("menu")) {
        var item = {
          name: route.name,
          icon: route.menu.icon
        };
        if(route.hasOwnProperty("children") && route.children.length > 0) {
          item.children = iterateArrayRoutes(route.children);
        }
        last.push(item);
      }
      return last;
    }, []);
    return routeFormatted;
  }
};
```

Here you have a Demo https://jsfiddle.net/vm1hrwLL/